# C# recursive method returns 0 on second iteration for int.TryParse

Tags: c#

Using a quick int validation for a user's input on a console app. If a user passes in a value that causes the `TryParse` to fail, the method calls itself again. When this happens (second or any additional occurrences), the value is always `0`. The same happens when I use an `Enum.TryParse` (different method) as well, it returns the FIRST value of the `Enum`.

```
// main method

var currentRowNumber = GetSpaceNumber("Enter Number:");
Console.WriteLine(currentRowNumber);  // will output "0" when any TryParse fails in below method
```

---

```
private static int GetSpaceNumber(string instructions)
{
     Console.WriteLine(instructions);

     int numberPassed;

     // tried assigning the "result" to a one liner from Console.ReadLine(), and using that variable in the TryParse method as well, same result
     if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberPassed))
     {
         GetSpaceNumber(instructions);
     }

     return numberPassed;
}
```

---

```
Output:

Enter Number: 
a  // this obviously fails and awaits another user input
5  // from user input
0  // from WriteLine in main method


Working Example: (if the TryParse doesn't fail)

Enter Number:
5  // from user input
5  // from WriteLine
```

---

The same happens when I use an `Enum` as well (as described above)

```
public enum Example
{
    Test1,
    Test2
}
```

---

```
// main method

var currentPiceType = GetPieceType();
Console.WriteLine(currentPiceType);
```

```
private static PieceType GetPieceType()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Piece Type: Test1, Test2");

    PieceType result;
    if (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
         GetPieceType();
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

```
Output:

Enter Piece Type: Test1, Test2
abc // from user input
Test2 // from user input
Test1 // from WriteLine()

Working Example:

Enter Piece Type: Test1, Test2
Test2 // from user input
Test2 // from WriteLine()
```

How can I code this differently (without using global variables, unless that's the only way) so that the correct value is returned from the method when called recursively. Also, could you please explain WHY this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `GetSpaceNumber(instructions);` What are you doing with the return value of that call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the results from the recursion, otherwise even when your validation passes, it never gets returned

```
private static int GetSpaceNumber(string instructions)
{
     Console.WriteLine(instructions);

     int numberPassed;

     if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberPassed))
     {
         // here
         return GetSpaceNumber(instructions);
     }

     return numberPassed;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd mark this as answer as correct if I could, but other guy answered just before you. Cheers

Comment: @RobScott not according to the time stamps :), all good though, good luck

Comment: @RobScott it some weird sorting behavior by SO,  TheGeneral was first)

Comment: Understood, I'll mark this as answered. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing return statement for your recursive call:

```
 if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberPassed))
 {
     return GetSpaceNumber(instructions); // add it here
 }
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Appreciate it

Comment: @RobScott, happens to even best of us. Was glad to help!